# SwiftUI: checking if next index exists in a ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am iterating through a ForEach and some arrays have 1 index and I want to leave those as-is.  For arrays with multiple indices, I want to separate the values by a pipe so at the end of each loop, I want to see if the a greater index exists by doing `$0 + 1` but I keep getting: `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected condition type 'Bool'` and `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected condition type 'Int'

```
ForEach(item.currency, id: \.self) {
    Text(verbatim: $0)
        .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
        .foregroundColor(Color("47B188"))
        .padding(.leading, 18)
                
    if (item.currency[$0 + 1]) {
        Text("|")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate your collection indices and check if the index + 1 is less then the collection endIndex:

```
ForEach(item.currency.indices) {
    Text(verbatim: item.currency[$0])
        .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
        .foregroundColor(Color("47B188"))
        .padding(.leading, 18)
    if $0 + 1 < item.currency.endIndex {
        Text("|")
    }
}
```

Comment: oh cool, didnt know you could iterate over the indices like that.  thank you